# Jasperserver FAIL - Application at context path [/jasperserver] could not be started

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jasperserver

I can't run jasperserver. I have tried reinstall with bundle version (tomcat 8.5) and also with another (9.0) versions of tomcat. [tomcatmanager screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1JfQ.png) . Services jasperreportsTomcat and jasperreportsPostrgreSQL are running [services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdRMB.png) . [run from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRhoq.png) Logs from tomcat [local host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJZNs.png) and catalina:

```
27-Sep-2020 14:37:09.617 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-46] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars  
least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a 
complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during 
scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
27-Sep-2020 14:37:23.252 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-46] 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full 
details will be found in the appropriate container log file
27-Sep-2020 14:37:23.253 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-46] 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/jasperserver] startup failed due to 
previous errors
27-Sep-2020 14:37:23.318 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-46] 
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application 
[jasperserver] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-301] but has failed to stop it. This is 
very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.themes.ThemeCache$RefreshThread.run(ThemeCache.java:332)
27-Sep-2020 14:37:23.319 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-46] 
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application 
[jasperserver] appears to have started a thread named [pool-36-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. 
This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)  
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await
(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:550)
jmxlogger.tools.JmxLogService$3.run(JmxLogService.java:214)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Please help me. This is useful in my first project :-)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by installing Jasper Server version 7.5 and delete .jrsks and .jrsksp from C:/users/[username here] before intalation. I chose everythink bundled during installation.